# Formatting the output in R

Tags: r, format, output

I have a set of data which shows the visit ID and the subject name

```
visit<-c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,3)
subject<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","E","E","E")
data<-data.frame(visit=visit,subject=subject)
```

I attempted to work out the latest visit ID for each subject:

```
tapply(visit,subject,max)
```

And I get this output:

```
A B C D E
3 2 1 3 3
```

I am wondering if there is any way that I can change the output such that it becomes:

```
A  3
B  2
C  1
D  3
E  3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And a `dplyr` solution would be:

```
library(dyplr)  
data %>% group_by(subject) %>% summarize(max = max(visit))
## Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

##   subject max
## 1       A   3
## 2       B   2
## 3       C   1
## 4       D   3
## 5       E   3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `aggregate`

```
aggregate(visit~subject, data, max)
#   subject visit
#1       A     3
#2       B     2
#3       C     1
#4       D     3
#5       E     3
```

Or from `tapply`

```
res <- tapply(visit,subject,max)
data.frame(subject=names(res), visit=res)
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(visit=max(visit)), by=subject]
```

Answer (score 1):

It may feel dirty, but using the base function `as.matrix` (or `matrix` for that matter) will give you what you need.

```
> as.matrix(tapply(visit,subject,max))
  [,1]
A    3
B    2
C    1
D    3
E    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in base R with `stack`:

```
stack(tapply(visit, subject, max))
#   values ind
# 1      3   A
# 2      2   B
# 3      1   C
# 4      3   D
# 5      3   E
```

(Note: In this case, the values for "visit" and "subject" aren't actually coming from your `data.frame`. Just thought you should know!)

---

(Second note: You could also do `data.frame(as.table(tapply(visit, subject, max)))` but that is more deceptive than using `stack` so may lead to less readable code later on.)